# How do I re-write Gridview data to an XML file on button click? ASP.Net VB

Tags: asp.net, xml, vb.net

This is a continuation from my previous post, I'm using a Gridview in a submission form along with textboxes controls. Upon clicking the submit button, the information is rendered to an xml file. Each time the form is used, my intention is to have the xml file populate w/ the newly entered data, thus overwritting that entered from previous submissions. The user needs to be able to input multiple product numbers, which is my reason for using an editable Gridview in the submission form. My problem is that when the submit button is clicked, the data entered from the textboxes are copied over to the xml file, but the data from the Gridview is overwitten. Though, I'm able to Edit/Insert/Delete data to the XML file via the Gridview. the gridview data fails to save to the xml file:

The following is my design:

```
  <div>
    <!--Grdiview -->
    <div>
        <asp:GridView ID="gvProductNumber" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                        onrowdeleting="gvProductNumber_RowDeleting" onrowediting="gvProductNumber_RowEditing"
                        onrowupdating="gvProductNumber_RowUpdating" onrowcommand="gvProductNumber_RowCommand"
                        ShowFooter="True" Width="482px"
                        onrowcancelingedit="gvProductNumber_RowCancelingEdit">
                        <Columns>
                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Product ID">
                                <EditItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtProductID" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("productID") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                                </EditItemTemplate>
                                <FooterTemplate>
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtProductIDInsert" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                                </FooterTemplate>
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:Label ID="lblProductID" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("ProductID") %>'></asp:Label>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                             <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Product Number">
                                <EditItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtProductNumber" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("productNumber") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                                </EditItemTemplate>
                                <FooterTemplate>
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtProductNumberInsert" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                                </FooterTemplate>
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:Label ID="lblProductNumber" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("ProductNumber") %>'></asp:Label>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                            <asp:TemplateField ShowHeader="False">
                                <EditItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" CausesValidation="True"
                                        CommandName="Update" Text="Update"></asp:LinkButton>
                                    &nbsp;<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton2" runat="server" CausesValidation="False"
                                        CommandName="Cancel" Text="Cancel"></asp:LinkButton>
                                </EditItemTemplate>
                                <FooterTemplate>
                                    <asp:LinkButton ID="btnInsert" runat="server" CommandName="insertXMLData">Insert</asp:LinkButton>
                                </FooterTemplate>
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" CausesValidation="False"
                                        CommandName="Edit" Text="Edit"></asp:LinkButton>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                                <ItemStyle Width="120px" />
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                            <asp:CommandField ShowDeleteButton="True" />
                         </Columns>
                    </asp:GridView>   
    </div>
    <!--end gridview -->



           <br /><br />

           <div> 
            <div><p>Last Name:&nbsp; <asp:TextBox id="txtLastName" runat="server" /></p></div>
            <div><p>First Name:&nbsp; <asp:TextBox id="txtFirstName" runat="server" /></p></div>
            <div><p>Street Address:&nbsp; <asp:TextBox id="txtAddress" runat="server" /></p></div>
            <div><p>City:&nbsp; <asp:TextBox id="txtCity" runat="server" /></p></div>
            <div><p>State:&nbsp; <asp:TextBox id="txtState" runat="server" /></p></div>
            <div><p>Zip Code:&nbsp; <asp:TextBox id="txtZipCode" runat="server" /></p></div>
            <div><asp:Button id="btnWriteXml" OnClick="Write_XML" Text="Write XML File" runat="server" /></div>
          </div>
    </div>
```

This is my code behind, this is where I'm trying to re-write the data from the Grid to the xml file and at the same time, write the data that is inputted via the text-box controls:

'Write the results to the xml file

```
   Public Sub Write_XML(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
        'You have saved xml, now want to add data thorugh text boxes

        Dim dsgvPersonalData As New DataSet()
        dsgvPersonalData.ReadXml(Server.MapPath("~/xml/PersonDataVI.xml"))

        'Add new Product
        Dim drNewProduct As DataRow = dsgvPersonalData.Tables("product").NewRow()
        Dim productID As String = DirectCast(gvProductNumber.FooterRow.FindControl("txtProductIDInsert"), TextBox).Text
        Dim productNumber As String = DirectCast(gvProductNumber.FooterRow.FindControl("txtProductNumberInsert"), TextBox).Text
        drNewProduct("productID") = productID
        drNewProduct("productNumber") = productNumber
        dsgvPersonalData.Tables("product").Rows.Add(drNewProduct)

        'Add new Customer
        Dim drNewCustomer As DataRow = dsgvPersonalData.Tables("customer").NewRow()
        drNewProduct("LastName") = txtLastName.Text
        drNewProduct("FirstName") = txtFirstName.Text
        drNewProduct("Address") = txtAddress.Text
        drNewProduct("City") = txtCity.Text
        drNewProduct("State") = txtState.Text
        drNewProduct("ZipCode") = txtZipCode.Text
        dsgvPersonalData.Tables("customer").Rows.Add(drNewProduct)

        'Save the xml
        dsgvPersonalData.WriteXml(Server.MapPath("~/xml/PersonDataVI.xml"))

        'databinding is easy here
        gvProductNumber.DataSource = dsgvPersonalData.Tables("product")
        gvProductNumber.DataBind()
    End Sub
```

The xml I'm attempting to generate:

```
  <PersonalData>
  <products>
    <product>
      <productID>1</productID>
      <productNumber>123456</productNumber>
    </product>
    <product>
      <productID>2</productID>
      <productNumber>458922</productNumber>
    </product>
    <product>
      <productID>4</productID>
      <productNumber>224578</productNumber>
    </product>
    <product>
      <productID>5</productID>
      <productNumber>789012</productNumber>
    </product>
  </products>
  <customers>
    <customer>
      <LastName>Doe</LastName>
      <FirstName>Jane</FirstName>
      <Address>1456 somewhere Dr.</Address>
      <City>Frisco</City>
      <State>California</State>
      <ZipCode>59045</ZipCode>
    </customer>
  </customers>
</PersonalData>
```

As mentioned, the xml from the gridiview fails to re-write to the xml file on button-click;
Please, could I get some direction as to what I'm doing wrong here. I fill that I'm close. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are duplicating logic.

**EDIT:** the code below should work.

```
Imports System.Collections.Generic
Imports System.Linq
Imports System.Web
Imports System.Web.UI
Imports System.Web.UI.WebControls
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Xml



Public Class Default6_gridview
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        If Not Page.IsPostBack Then
            BindGridView()
        End If
    End Sub
    'Bind Data
    Protected Sub BindGridView()
        Dim dsgvProductNumber As New DataSet()
        dsgvProductNumber.ReadXml(Server.MapPath("~/xml/PersonDataVI.xml"))
        gvProductNumber.DataSource = dsgvProductNumber.Tables("product")
        gvProductNumber.DataBind()
        gvProductNumber.ShowFooter = True
    End Sub
    'Delete
    Protected Sub gvProductNumber_RowDeleting(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As GridViewDeleteEventArgs)
        BindGridView()
        Dim dsgvProductNumber As New DataSet()
        dsgvProductNumber.ReadXml(Server.MapPath("~/xml/PersonDataVI.xml"))
        dsgvProductNumber.Tables("product").Rows(gvProductNumber.Rows(e.RowIndex).DataItemIndex).Delete()
        dsgvProductNumber.WriteXml(Server.MapPath("~/xml/PersonDataVI.xml"))
        BindGridView()
    End Sub
    'Row edit
    Protected Sub gvProductNumber_RowEditing(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As GridViewEditEventArgs)
        gvProductNumber.ShowFooter = False
        gvProductNumber.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex
        BindGridView()
    End Sub
    'Update GridView
    Protected Sub gvProductNumber_RowUpdating(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As GridViewUpdateEventArgs)
        Dim index As Integer = gvProductNumber.Rows(e.RowIndex).DataItemIndex
        Dim productId As String = DirectCast(gvProductNumber.Rows(e.RowIndex).FindControl("txtProductID"), TextBox).Text
        Dim productNumber As String = DirectCast(gvProductNumber.Rows(e.RowIndex).FindControl("txtProductNumber"), TextBox).Text
        gvProductNumber.EditIndex = -1
        BindGridView()

        Dim dsgvProductNumber As New DataSet()
        dsgvProductNumber.ReadXml(Server.MapPath("~/xml/PersonDataVI.xml"))
        dsgvProductNumber.Tables("product").Rows(index)("productID") = productId
        dsgvProductNumber.Tables("product").Rows(index)("productNumber") = productNumber
        dsgvProductNumber.WriteXml(Server.MapPath("~/xml/PersonDataVI.xml"))
        BindGridView()
    End Sub
    'Cancel
    Protected Sub gvProductNumber_RowCancelingEdit(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As GridViewCancelEditEventArgs)
        gvProductNumber.EditIndex = -1
        BindGridView()
    End Sub
    'Insert New Row
    Protected Sub gvProductNumber_RowCommand(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As GridViewCommandEventArgs)
        If e.CommandName = "insertXMLData" Then
            Dim productID As String = DirectCast(gvProductNumber.FooterRow.FindControl("txtProductIDInsert"), TextBox).Text
            Dim productNumber As String = DirectCast(gvProductNumber.FooterRow.FindControl("txtProductNumberInsert"), TextBox).Text
            BindGridView()
            Dim dtXMLInsert As DataTable = DirectCast(gvProductNumber.DataSource, DataTable)

            Dim dsgvProductNumber As New DataSet()
            dsgvProductNumber.ReadXml(Server.MapPath("~/xml/PersonDataVI.xml"))
            Dim drInsert As DataRow = dsgvProductNumber.Tables("product").NewRow()
            drInsert("productID") = productID
            drInsert("productNumber") = productNumber
            Dim drParent As DataRow = dsgvProductNumber.Tables("product").Rows(0)
            drInsert.SetParentRow(drParent)
            dsgvProductNumber.Tables("product").Rows.Add(drInsert)
            dsgvProductNumber.WriteXml(Server.MapPath("~/xml/PersonDataVI.xml"))

            BindGridView()
        End If

    End Sub
    'Write the results to the xml file
    'Public Sub Write_XML(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    '    Dim textWriter As New XmlTextWriter(Server.MapPath("xml/PersonDataVI.xml"), Nothing)
    '    textWriter.Formatting = System.Xml.Formatting.Indented
    '    'Start New Document
    '    textWriter.WriteStartDocument()
    '    'Write a Comment
    '    textWriter.WriteComment("This is a comment")
    '    'Insert Start Element -root element node
    '    textWriter.WriteStartElement("PersonalData")
    '    'write the child element
    '    textWriter.WriteStartElement("products")
    '    'write the child element
    '    textWriter.WriteStartElement("product")
    '    'Write ProductID Element and Data
    '    textWriter.WriteStartElement("productID", "")
    '    textWriter.WriteString(txtProductID.Text)
    '    textWriter.WriteEndElement()
    '    'Write ProductNumber Element and Data
    '    textWriter.WriteStartElement("productNumber", "")
    '    textWriter.WriteString(txtProductNum.Text)
    '    textWriter.WriteEndElement()

    '    textWriter.WriteEndElement()
    '    textWriter.WriteEndElement()
    '    'write the child element
    '    textWriter.WriteStartElement("customers")
    '    'write the child element
    '    textWriter.WriteStartElement("customer")
    '    'Write LastName Element and Data
    '    textWriter.WriteStartElement("LastName", "")
    '    textWriter.WriteString(txtLastName.Text)
    '    textWriter.WriteEndElement()
    '    'Write FirstName Element and Data
    '    textWriter.WriteStartElement("FirstName", "")
    '    textWriter.WriteString(txtFirstName.Text)
    '    textWriter.WriteEndElement()
    '    'Write Address Element and Data
    '    textWriter.WriteStartElement("Address", "")
    '    textWriter.WriteString(txtAddress.Text)
    '    textWriter.WriteEndElement()
    '    'Write City Element and Data
    '    textWriter.WriteStartElement("City", "")
    '    textWriter.WriteString(txtCity.Text)
    '    textWriter.WriteEndElement()
    '    'Write State Element and Data
    '    textWriter.WriteStartElement("State", "")
    '    textWriter.WriteString(txtState.Text)
    '    textWriter.WriteEndElement()
    '    'Write ZipCode Elment and Data
    '    textWriter.WriteStartElement("ZipCode", "")
    '    textWriter.WriteString(txtZipCode.Text)
    '    textWriter.WriteEndElement()
    '    'End Everything
    '    textWriter.WriteEndDocument()
    '    'Clean up
    '    textWriter.Flush()
    '    textWriter.Close()
    '    'Display the XML Document
    '    Response.Redirect(Server.MapPath("xml/PersonDataVI.xml"))

    '    'You have saved xml, now want to add data thorugh text boxes
    '    Dim dsgvPersonalData As New DataSet()
    '    dsgvPersonalData.ReadXml(Server.MapPath("~/xml/PersonDataVI.xml"))

    '    'Add new Product
    '    Dim drNewProduct As DataRow = dsgvPersonalData.Tables("product").NewRow()
    '    Dim productID As String = DirectCast(gvProductNumber.FooterRow.FindControl("txtProductIDInsert"), TextBox).Text
    '    Dim productNumber As String = DirectCast(gvProductNumber.FooterRow.FindControl("txtProductNumberInsert"), TextBox).Text
    '    drNewProduct("productID") = productID
    '    drNewProduct("productNumber") = productNumber

    '    'add in the parent
    '    'Dim drParentTbl As DataRow = dsgvPersonalData.Tables("product").Rows(0)
    '    'drNewProduct.SetParentRow(drParentTbl)

    '    dsgvPersonalData.Tables("product").Rows.Add(drNewProduct)

    '    'Add new Customer
    '    Dim drNewCustomer As DataRow = dsgvPersonalData.Tables("customers").NewRow()
    '    drNewProduct("LastName") = txtLastName.Text
    '    drNewProduct("FirstName") = txtFirstName.Text
    '    drNewProduct("Address") = txtAddress.Text
    '    drNewProduct("City") = txtCity.Text
    '    drNewProduct("State") = txtState.Text
    '    drNewProduct("ZipCode") = txtZipCode.Text
    '    dsgvPersonalData.Tables("customers").Rows.Add(drNewProduct)

    '    'Save the xml
    '    dsgvPersonalData.WriteXml(Server.MapPath("~/xml/PersonDataVI.xml"))

    '    'databinding is easy here
    '    gvProductNumber.DataSource = dsgvPersonalData.Tables("product")
    '    gvProductNumber.DataBind()

    'End Sub

    Public Sub Write_XML(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
        'You have saved xml, now want to add data thorugh text boxes

        Dim dsgvPersonalData As New DataSet()
        dsgvPersonalData.ReadXml(Server.MapPath("~/xml/PersonDataVI.xml"))

        'Add new Product
        Dim drNewProduct As DataRow = dsgvPersonalData.Tables("product").NewRow()
        Dim productID As String = DirectCast(gvProductNumber.FooterRow.FindControl("txtProductIDInsert"), TextBox).Text
        Dim productNumber As String = DirectCast(gvProductNumber.FooterRow.FindControl("txtProductNumberInsert"), TextBox).Text
        drNewProduct("productID") = productID
        drNewProduct("productNumber") = productNumber
        dsgvPersonalData.Tables("product").Rows.Add(drNewProduct)

        'Add new Customer
        Dim drNewCustomer As DataRow = dsgvPersonalData.Tables("customer").NewRow()
        drNewCustomer("LastName") = txtLastName.Text
        drNewCustomer("FirstName") = txtFirstName.Text
        drNewCustomer("Address") = txtAddress.Text
        drNewCustomer("City") = txtCity.Text
        drNewCustomer("State") = txtState.Text
        drNewCustomer("ZipCode") = txtZipCode.Text
        dsgvPersonalData.Tables("customer").Rows.Add(drNewCustomer)

        'Save the xml
        dsgvPersonalData.WriteXml(Server.MapPath("~/xml/PersonDataVI.xml"))

        'databinding is easy here
        gvProductNumber.DataSource = dsgvPersonalData.Tables("product")
        gvProductNumber.DataBind()
    End Sub
End Class
```